# Can i install ipa signed by release(appstore) profile on my iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

Can i install ipa signed by release(appstore) profile on my iphone, befor submitting it to app store.

If yes, how?

Comment: Have you looked at using [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)? - [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW2)

Answer (score 1):

If the ipa is generated using Distribution certificate and Provisioning profile as seems like in you case then **No** you can not install it on your device.